# Adding SQL query to JSON Payload

Tags: javascript, json, rest

I need to send SQL query to REST API in JSON format, it worked for simple query but I am trying to use WHERE clause with IN operator. It is working in Postman if I hardcode the value but it seems not working as expected when I pass array of Input to IN operator.

```
var servers = ['Server-1','Server-2'];
var requestBody = {};
requestBody.Script = 'SELECT ID, NAME, FQDN FROM SERVER WHERE Name IN ('+servers+')';
gs.log("Advanced Request3 Body: "+JSON.stringify(requestBody));
```

This is Output:

```
{"Script":"SELECT ID, NAME, FQDN FROM SERVER WHERE Name IN (Server-1,Server-2)"}
```

This is expected output: can anyone help if anything wrong in passing array.

```
{"Script":"SELECT ID, NAME, FQDN FROM SERVER WHERE Name IN ('Server-1','Server-2')"}
```

Comment: Well you need to escape the values you are interpolating in that string. But really an API (I wouldn't term it "REST") should absolutely not accept SQL. That's not just an [SQLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), it's just a wide open front door.

Comment: I am invoking cloud centrify endpoint to get server details '/Redrock/query' where payload should have query to return the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the single quotes for each element in the array, by using `Array.map`:

```
var serversEscaped = servers.map(function(el) { return '\'' + el + '\''; });
```

And then use `Array.join` to generate a string with commas:

```
var query = serversEscaped.join(', ');
```

Here's how your whole code could look like:

```
var servers = ['Server-1','Server-2'];
var requestBody = {};
var serversEscaped = servers.map(function(el) { return '\'' + el + '\''; });
var query = serversEscaped.join(', ');

requestBody.Script = 'SELECT ID, NAME, FQDN FROM SERVER WHERE Name IN ('+ query +');'
console.log(JSON.stringify(requestBody));
```